# How to identify one-one correspondance in Sufficient Statistics?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference, sufficient-statistics

[image]

The correct answer to the given question is (1),(3) and (4). I understood how 3 and 4 are correct but I could not understand how (1) is also a correct answer.

I know that here $\sum_i X_i$ is a sufficient statistic and any one-one function of this statistic is also a sufficient statistic but according to my calculations $X_1 + 2X_2$  is not a one-one function of $X_1 + X_2$.

My argument being that when $X_1 = 1$ and $X_2= 0$  or $X_1 =0$ and $X_2=1$ then $X_1 + X_2 =1$  but in case of $X_1 + 2X_2$, it takes value 1 or 2 respectively. 1 is matched with two values 1 and 2. Therefore, it is not a one-one function.

Comment: Think about the possible values of $(X_1,X_2)$ and of the corresponding values of $X_1+2X_2$.

Comment: I did, but i found that X1 + 2X2 is not a one one function.  Can you confirm that?

Comment: Okay, got you. So it is actually one-one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a general basis, the function
\begin{align*}
h: &\mathbb N^2 \longmapsto \mathbb N\\
   &(x,y) \longmapsto x+2y\\
\end{align*}
is neither bijective nor in one-to-one relation with the function
\begin{align*}
h: &\mathbb N^2 \longmapsto \mathbb N\\
   &(x,y) \longmapsto x+y\\
\end{align*}
However, the function
\begin{align*}
h: &\{0,1\}^2 \longmapsto \{0,1,2,3\}\\
   &(x,y) \longmapsto x+2y\\
\end{align*}
happens to be bijective, that is, for each different value of $x+2y$ there exists a single value of $(x,y)$. Therefore $X_1+2X_2$ contains the same amount of information as $(X_1,X_2)$ and is therefore trivially sufficient. It is correct however that it is not in bijection with $X_1+X_2$.

**Addendum:** I reproduced the multiple choice question in an exam last month and none of my students were able to select $X_1+2X_2$ with a proper explanation.